# Multiple firewalls one per authentication type

Tags: symfony

I am trying to implement token authentication (in addition to form login) by following these articles:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/api_key_authentication.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/multiple_user_providers.html

Here is my security.yaml:

```
main:
    anonymous: true
    pattern: ^/
    provider: db_provider

    form_login:
        login_path: auth_login
        check_path: auth_login

#secured_area:
    logout:
        path:   /auth/logout
        target: /         

token:
    anonymous: true
    pattern: ^/token

    stateless: false
    simple_preauth:
        authenticator: App\Security\TokenAuthenticator
    provider: token_user_provider
```

This doesn't work - the token authenticators never get called unless I comment out the "main" firewall.

I think I can achieve my requirement by following this article and using just "main" firewall:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/multiple_user_providers.html

However I would prefer the approach I am attempting right now because I don't want the token authenticator to fire on every single request I want it limited to just `/token` paths and I would rather avoid checking for the paths inside the `TokenAuthenticator::createToken(...)` as suggested in the docs:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/api_key_authentication.html#only-authenticating-for-certain-urls

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: You might check, it could be a route issue, since main is `^/` but your token pattern is more specific. What you're doing suggests you'd need to do `provider: [db_provider,token_user_provider]` in main as well.

Comment: Everything I have managed to read on multiple firewalls seems to imply this is possible though...chaining the providers is the official documented approach apparently.

Comment: If you make main `^/en/` or something more specific, it might work.

Comment: Ooops sorry I figured it out right after I posted - you tipped me off with your last remark I moved the more specific firewall above the ^/ catch-all and that seems to have done the trick